# Does this resemble to any known properties? My notes are wrong and my book doesn't say anything...

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions

I just started studying discrete probability distributions and after a little introduction there are a couple of rules (axioms most probably) about (that's what my notes state but I'm not a hundred percent sure) probability measures.

Here are the points:

- $\forall i \in [1,n]\cap \mathbb{N},\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\omega_j\in\Omega \quad \mathbb{P}( \{ w_j \}_{j=1}^{\infty}) = P_i$ and $\forall E\subseteq\Omega \quad \mathbb{P}(E) = \sum\limits_{j} \mathbb{P}(\omega_j)$
- $ P_i \geq 0 \quad \forall \text{ admissible } i $
- $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n P_i = 1$

I'm having hard times understanding what the first one is trying to say, (suspect some kind of badly formalized additivity?) and actually have some suspect that I copied them wrong...

Does anybody know what the first one should actually be?

Comment: Looks something like $\Omega$ is comprised of $\omega_{i,j}$, with finitely many $i$ and countably many $j$, and otherwise it has a typical probability measure on it. Not sure why you'd have this odd framework though...

Comment: @Ian: Does it really make any sense to do something like this?

Comment: Depends what you do afterwards really. It's definitely not fundamental.

Comment: @Ian: After this introduction it (in order) explains Dirac distribution, Bernoulli's trials, binomial distributions, De Moivre-Laplace theorem on binomial distribution, Bernoulli's theorem for central limit law, introduction to random variables, (using characteristic functions), expectation, variance and so on...

Comment: The first bullet point is definitely absurd, independently "of what you do afterwards really". This is a typo, either by you or by your book or by somebody else.

Comment: @Did: That's it!! It must be an error cause it's absurd. I still have read on this website long time ago (I don't really recall the post) some post written in similar notations, like with $\mathbb{P}(\omega_j)$ or something, so I was hoping that I could get some enlightment right here.

Comment: Do you have a textbook or something similar as a reference, or just lecture notes? (If so, which textbook?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote my teacher, who told me that the correct one was:

$\text{Let} \;\; \mathbb{P}(\{\omega_j\}_{j=1}^n)  = P_j \;\;\;\forall \omega_j\in\Omega \;\; $ where $\{\omega_j\}$ has at most countably many elements.

Then $\forall$ Event $E \subset \Omega\quad \mathbb{P}(E) = \sum\limits_{j| \omega_j\in E} P_j$